# java script alert message doesn't seem to show

Tags: javascript, html, plsql, toad

so-far I have tried everything. My code is below but when I run it nothing seems to happen, nor do I get any error messages. I'm working with Toad for oracle, so I'm literally hard-coding

-- form field and button --

```
http.p ('<input type="form" method="post" name="idstu" id="idstu" placeholder="e.g. 000123456">');
                htp.br;
                htp.p (' <input type="submit" onclick="confirmMsg()" value="Submit">');
```

-- javascript --

```
http.p ('<script type="text/javascript">
                    function confirmMsg() {
                    var field1 = document.getElementById("idstu").value;
                    alert(field1 "has been unsuspended");   
                    }');
```

Comment: don't you neet do concatenate the variable and sting in your alert?

alert(field1 + "has been unsuspended");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the working answer.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function confirmMsg() {
                    var field1 = document.getElementById("idstu").value;
                    alert(field1+"has been unsuspended");
                    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="form" method="post" name="idstu" id="idstu" placeholder="e.g. 000123456">
<input type="submit" onclick="confirmMsg()" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing `type=submit` in `<input>` tag.

Comment: well i have used the type as "button" before but that hasnt worked either.

Comment: If you put this in your answer above, the page doesn't have to be long. So people don't have to scroll that much:)

Answer (score 0):

your code would be causing error .

```
<input type="form" method="post" name="idstu" id="idstu" placeholder="e.g. 000123456">
```

it should be type='text'.And alert should be like :

```
alert(field1+"has been unsuspended");
}
</script> <!--must have the habit to close each tag -->
```

Comment: yes, i have tried that aswell. but again no alert messages on onclick.

Comment: still nothing. i have changed it over several times to see what would work. but again i get no error message nor do i get an alert message. just to be clear. i am coding this in plsql and html using toad for oracle

Answer (score 0):

i've got it to work. first of all as @liju mentioned i didn't close the script tag as i have thousands of lines(stupid mistake). 2nd i played around with the code again and changed the input types of both field and button. now i do get the alert message. Thanks everyone . 
--working code below. --

```
htp.p ('<input type="text" method="post" name="idstu" id="idstu" placeholder="e.g. 000123456">');
            htp.br;
            htp.p (' <input type="button" onclick="confirmMsg()" value="Submit">');

htp.p ('<script type="text/javascript">
                    function confirmMsg() {
                    var field1 = document.getElementById("idstu").value;
                    alert(field1+"has been unsuspended");
                    }   
                    </script>');
```